# Windows Phone 8 expandable list view

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to implement expandable list view on windows phone 8. My target is to bind the values from JSON output which i receive as parent child format.

Comment: Please provide code you did and where you blocked, explain what's your problem, StackOverflow is not a place to ask people to do your whole work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are wanting something similar to Androids [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)?

If so, then take a look at Windows Phone Toolkits [ExpanderView](https://phone.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The WPToolkit has a pretty awesome ExpanderView control. Check it out

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-expanderview-in-depth-part1-key-concepts-and-api

If you want to make a custom solution, in your datatemplate add a grid whose visibility is bound to your model property and on ListBox SelectionChanged, toggle the value of that property